# Quantum Field Theory: infinitesimal Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory, lie-algebra

In the Brandhuber lecture notes, it says at the section about Dirac equation under lorentz transformation that we can consider an **infinitesimal Lorentz transformation** like this one,

$$
\Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu} = \delta^\nu_\mu - i \delta \omega^\nu_\mu
$$

Where does that "formula" come from?

In particular I don't understand where does the $- i$ come from? and what is $\omega^\nu_\mu$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)?

Comment: Not really. We should speak about that next week in the QFT class I think. However, I'm gonna take a group theory class next semester.

Comment: It's just saying that, since the identity $I$ is a (trivial) L.T., and (like rotations) they are continuous, we can consider a L.T. 'near' the identity by expanding it into a sum of the identity $I$, and a 'small' matrix $\delta \omega'$ where 'small' means the entries in the matrix $\delta \omega'$ are so small we can ignore those in $(\delta \omega')^2$. We can then say $\Lambda^a_b = \delta^a_b + \delta \omega'^a_b = \delta^a_b + i (-i\delta \omega'^a_b) = \delta^a_b + i \delta \omega^a_b$. The $i$ is a convention related to Lie algebras and wanting Hermitian vs. anti-Hermitian generators.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the Lorentz group are generated by exponentiation of boosts and rotation generators ($J_i$ and $K_i$ respectively)  as follows:

$\Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu} = e^{-i (\theta_i J^{i, \nu}_{\mu} + \beta_i K^{i, \nu}_{\mu})}$

So for infinitesimal transformations we can expand the exponential up to first order as follows:

$\Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu} \approx \delta_{\mu}^{\nu} - i \theta_i J^{i, \nu}_{\mu} - i \beta_i K^{i, \nu}_{\mu} = \delta_{\mu}^{\nu} - i \omega_{\mu}^{\nu}$

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are not familiar with Lie groups, here is an explanation "by hand".

You can parametrise the Lorentz transformations as $\Lambda(\beta_i,\alpha_j)$ where the three components of $\beta$ are the velocity vector for the boost part of the transformation and $\alpha$ contains the angles for the rotation part.

Now when people are talking about "infinitesimal Lorentz transformations" they mean the following: Pick curves $s \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \beta_i(s)$
and $s \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \alpha_j(s)$ that are 0 at $s=0$. Then for each set of such curves we get a curve in the space of Lorentztransformations (think a curve in the space of 4 times 4 matrices) as:

$\Lambda(s) = \Lambda(\beta_i(s), \alpha_j(s))$.

We can Tailor expand this curve around $0$ to get

$\Lambda(s) = \Lambda(0) + \omega(0) s + ...$ = $1 + \omega s + ...$

The four by four matrix $\omega$ is then considered as an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation. One can easily verify, that $\omega$ needs to be antisymmetric. Just tailor expand the L.h.s of

$\Lambda(s)^T \eta \Lambda(s) = \eta $

and then compare both sides of the equation order by order. The $i$ is a convention that depends on what kind of properties you want $\omega$ to have (without the $i$, $\omega$ is an antisymmetric matrix. So including the $i$ you have a Hermitian matrix which is nice for QM).